# Android create your own menu

Tags: android, menu

I want to build my own menu from the beginning so to be able to put more then 3 items on a raw and put a custom theme. I know it's possible because I saw in other applications, but I am new in Android and I don't know how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem after all. I made a popup window and worked :D.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) in Android Developer Guides.